# Diamond shaped numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

Good day all
i have some code which i desired to render a diamond shaped numbers using javascripts
it used 2 javascript function on 1 onclick,
but somehow the other functions seems not working

here are the html markup for the code

```
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="pyramid.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
     <center>
     <table>
      <tr><td>Enter a number</td><td><input type="text" id="no" class="nomor" name="number"></td></tr>
       <tr><td></td><td><input type=submit value="submit" id="pattern" onclick="Pyramid(document.getElementById('no').value);Pyramiddn(document.getElementById('no').value);"></td></tr>


  </body>
</html>
```

and here is the javascript markup

```
function Pyramid(number)

        {
          document.write("<center>"); // this to align the output in center
          if(number>0)     
           {
             Pyramid(number-1);   //this is to move through the number of iterations
             for(j=1;j<=number;j++)   //this loop is to print the numbers in ascending order
             {
               document.write(" "+j);
             }

             for(k=number-1;k>0;k--)    // this loop is to print the numbers in descending order
             {
               document.write(" "+k);
             }

           } 
           document.write("<br>");


        } ;

function Pyramiddn(number)
        {
          document.write("<center>"); // this to align the output in center
          if(number>0)     
           {
            //this is to move through the number of iterations

               for(i=1;i<=number;i++)   //this loop is to print the numbers in ascending order
             {
               document.write(" "+i);
             }

             for(l=number-1;l>0;l--)    // this loop is to print the numbers in descending order
             {
               document.write(" "+l);
             } 
               Pyramiddn(number-1); 
           } 
           document.write("<br>");


        } ;
```

The desired result is to create diamond shaped numbers from those 2 functions like

```
            1
          1 2 1
        1 2 3 2 1
      1 2 3 4 3 2 1
    1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
  1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
  1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1
    1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1
      1 2 3 4 3 2 1
        1 2 3 2 1
          1 2 1
            1
```

Comment: What's the question? What isn't working?

Comment: Ah, center <3, i didn't see it for a long time...

Comment: the code which i attach above only renders the top parts of the diamond meanwhile there is already a function which supposed to render full shape of diamond but the function seems not working.

Comment: Separated, both functions are working, you should avoid document write, problem lies there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead two functions, and two calls, and `document.write()` you can use one function, one call, build string and place string inside container, like this:

```
function diamond(number) {
line='';
//up
for(i=1;i<=number;i++) {

    for(j=1;j<=i;j++) {

        line+=' '+j; //left

    }
    for(j=i;j>1;j--) {

        line+=' '+(j-1); //right

    }


    line+='<br>';
}

//down
for(i=number-1;i>=1;i--) {

    for(j=1;j<=i;j++) {

        line+=' '+j; //left

    }
    for(j=i;j>1;j--) {

        line+=' '+(j-1); //right

    }


    line+='<br>';
}



    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=line;

}
```

Demo:

```js
function diamond(number) {
  line='';
  //up
  for(i=1;i<=number;i++) {
   
   for(j=1;j<=i;j++) {
    
    line+=' '+j; //left
    
   }
   for(j=i;j>1;j--) {
    
    line+=' '+(j-1); //right
    
   }
   
   
   line+='<br>';
  }
  
  //down
  for(i=number-1;i>=1;i--) {
   
   for(j=1;j<=i;j++) {
    
    line+=' '+j; //left
    
   }
   for(j=i;j>1;j--) {
    
    line+=' '+(j-1); //right
    
   }
   
   
   line+='<br>';
  }
  
   
   
   document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=line;
   
  }
```

```css
#result {
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>Enter a number</td><td><input type="text" id="no" class="nomor" name="number"></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td><input type=submit value="submit" id="pattern" onclick="diamond(document.getElementById('no').value);"></td></tr>
</table>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

Also, instead old and deprecated center tag, you should centralize result html with CSS:

```
#result {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Wow, What a total rebuild, but i like your solutions. it's make the result match with my desired output. Thanks for the feedback, i feel i need to learn more deep about javascript.